In google colab, problem when trying to open Apache Parquet file
In google colab, below error comes when trying to open Apache parquet file. How to solve it?
I have tried opening by dask also. It didnt work
I was expecting it would open by dask or by using pandas pyarrow.
how I can improvise below code:
import pandas as pd

try:
    df = pd.read_parquet('/content/sample_data/0.parquet')
    print(df)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")


What below error? Instead of improvise you mean something else?

@JamesZ
Error would say, "Parquet magic bytes not found" , which means some footer or metadata may be missing.
By improvize, I mean if I could fix on this above code to get rid of this error.
On inspection, this is valid Apache Parquet file
